# Does a covering nonclustered index help to answer Select * queries?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, index-tuning

Our application developers run a lot of `SELECT *` queries against our database system, unfortunately.

The missing index suggestions of *sys.dm_db_missing_index* contain a lot of cases that indicate to create a 100% covering non-clustered index for those cases. For example actually there is an index with 3 index columns and additional 25 included columns suggested. Other indexes with the key columns suggested are already in place but then require lookups.

I am a little surprised about this. However since the underlying queries are running *very* often with high costs and the suggested index comes with an impact of about 50% this is maybe an interesting option.

I know it is not best practice and bad design to support those queries, but I doubt this could be changed within adequate time, so I wonder if those indexes will help at all or produce more costs than benefit?

Is there a rule or do I just have to try / error the consequences?

- Row counts are between 60,000 and 2.1 million.
- The missing indexes DMVs tell me on average (over multiple servers) 2424 seek operations could be performed for the queries (this is a number counting up continuously for about 3 months and the query cost of 19 in average could be impacted positively of about 50%.
- Removing `SELECT *` would be best, but I am asked to optimize it as is, and since SQL Server itself suggests this, I think it is worth thinking about it anyway.
- The existing queries are not really slow, < 1 sec, but this is quite subjective as well I think. Execution plan tells the key lookups cost 80% of the whole, so I guess saving this might be desirable anyways.
- I did some tests without / with the 100% covering index. Results:

  `SELECT *` :  Costs before: 0,026 after: 0,00329 (new index used) = -88% improvement
  `UPDATE`: before: 0,043333 after: 0,0533 (ix used) = +20%
  `INSERT`: before: 0,1133 after: 0,1233 (ix not used)=equal
  `DELETE`: before: 0,645 after: 0,655 (ix used) =equal.

  Conclusion: It tunes the selects much more than it slows down the changes. Why not apply?

Comment: Then I guess it depends on how often the queries run and how many rows they return. If a query returns 10 rows and can find them from an index seek (and then lookup) from a 10M rows table, then I wouldn't create a 25-column INCLUDE index.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The missing index suggestions are *opportunistic* entries added whenever the optimizer happens to notice that an exact-match index for the current set of predicates it is considering do not exist on the base object.

The information recorded in the DMVs is intended to be a helpful input to the normal activities of a skilled database tuner; it is *not* intended to be interpreted as the result of a comprehensive analysis. The data recorded is intentionally a complete set of the keys and other columns needed, together with a brief indication of the reason it was added (equality, inequality, include).

The "impact" recorded is also very basic: it is the difference in *estimated* cost, according to the cost model used by the optimizer. As usual, this needs to be treated with a healthy dose of skepticism, because it is very unlikely that the *actual* performance characteristics of your hardware match the optimizer's model, even vaguely.

Note also that cost estimations depend heavily on cardinality (row count), average row size, and distribution information. If these are not reasonably close to the actual values, the "cost" is an even less reliable metric. Nevertheless, right now, estimated cost is all we have, so that's the number reported. Again, SQL Server is just trying to be as helpful as it can; it is up to the person reviewing the information to interpret it correctly.

Tests based on *estimated costs* are potentially informative to an early assessment of target areas for improvement, but they are no substitute for *actual measurements* of whatever metrics are important in your environment. The relative importance of duration, CPU usage, physical reads, memory usage ... and so on ... will be different in different circumstances.

The point really is to measure where the real problems are, record a baseline, make improvements, then measure and assess the benefits against the costs.

For a more thorough analysis than the missing index feature provides, you would need to run a representative workload through the Database Engine Tuning Advisor. Even there, the recommendations will still need to be assessed by a human, and something similar to the above baseline-assess-change-measure protocol followed.

That said, not all final decisions will be based on performance comparisons. There may be other considerations, like the avoidance of a particularly inconvenient lookup-related deadlock. Index tuning is as much art as science sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

Amending Paul's answer: You seem to be confused why an index that essentially copies the whole table can be beneficial. Indexes can be used to accelerate `WHERE` predicates and `ORDER BY` directives. The fact that your query plans have key lookups shows that the queries have at least a `WHERE` or an `ORDER BY` in them.

It is not at all an egregious thing to do to create a covering index for all columns of the table. This is a trade-off about query speed, write speed and space cost. You seem to have performed the required measurements already. If you like the results go ahead.

it is suspicious, though, that inserts and deletes have been measured as not slower than before. This might point to a flaw in the benchmark.

> Is there a rule or do I just have to try / error the consequences?

If you're familiar with how DQL and DML queries are executed under the hood you can often make predictions in your head about how different options will perform. Measuring is more reliable, though. But measurements can never test *all* cases. That's why an understanding of system internals is important, too.

Comment: Sure there is WHERE filtering in place. I am unsure if this is a helpful or not helpful answer because it stays very vague. But maybe my question is what is vague and so I can't expect a non-vague answer. After all, both of you did not explicitly give me a good reason NOT to apply the index and this makes my feeling go away that it may basically be a very bad idea to catch up some of the ugly SELECT * queries my favorite developers implemented using this index... And in the end this IS really helpful and makes me go ahead thinking about it and testing it again.

Comment: @Magier given the information in the question it is not possible to recommend a particular indexing strategy. An (actual) execution plan would be very helpful to do that.